# $Watch not working while watch text scope variable from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

$Watch not working while watch text scope variable from the controller. But scope is available for function call like "ng-blur", why not for $watch. What is wrong with my flow. Can anyone give suggestion

**Html**

```
<div ng-include="'html/bar.html'" ng-controller="barController"></div>
<div class="content-container view" data-ui-view>
    </div>
```

**bar.html**

```
<li data-ng-repeat="menu in menuData.menus" data-ng-init="menu.showSubMenu = false">
        <a class="main-menu" data-ng-click="menu.showSubMenu = !menu.showSubMenu">{{menu.menuName}}</a>
          <div data-ng-show="menu.showSubMenu && menu.subMenus" class="top-nav-menu-wrapper" style="display: block;">
              <div class="menu-container">
                <div class="drop-down-menu" style="display: block; top:10px;">
                  <div class="container-left" data-equalizer="">
                    <ul>
Menus li
</ul></div></div></div></div></li>
```

**barController**

```
$scope.$watch('menu.showSubMenu', function(newValue, oldValue) {
 console.log(newValue);
 if (newValue !== oldValue) {
  // stuff
 }
});

also tried this
$scope.$watchCollection('menu', function(newValue, oldValue) {
 console.log(newValue);
 if (newValue !== oldValue) {
  // stuff
 }
});
```

I gave context html only for understand scenario. here I need to access "menu.showSubMenu" variable from controller also update from controller while click on window to close sub menu

Comment: First why are you using `$watch`? while you can do stuff using `ng-change` which will more optimal solution. `<input type="text" ng-change="method()" ng-model="uutest" >`

Comment: yeah you are correct, but here just gave sample bro. Actually Exist application have init boolean variable using ng-init, now i need to access that variable value while click out side of sub menu( while click on window ) to hide sub menu

Comment: By looking your que. it is not clear what not working. The code seems fine to me. is ` console.log(newValue);` you getting in console.? Also  check if controller is loaded .

Comment: I have update context code above. kindly check that, and log not trigger while enter value in previous code text box. Now i give exactly what i expect

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates child scope. So `menu.showSubMenu` is accessible only inside the ng-repeat block. You can't access it inside controller .

Comment: Could you give me any idea to access that scope in anyway. Because i have access that while window click to close that sub menu.

Comment: `data-ng-init="menu.showSubMenu = newShowSubMenu  = false"` here `newShowSubMenu  ` is $scope variable and initialized inside ng-init. you can use it as reference for further.

Comment: I tried it now bro. but i could not access scope for "newShowSubMenu" while watch. Initially log by undefined while page load. but after then, it's not accessible. what happened

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and working fine

```
(function () {
"use strict";
define([], function () {
    return ['constantService', '$timeout', '$window', '$rootScope', function (constantService, $timeout, $window, $rootScope) {
        return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: false,
                link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                  var w = angular.element($window);
                  var tempScope = '';
                  console.log(scope.$parent.menu);
                  scope.$parent.$watch('menu.showSubMenu', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                    console.log(newValue);
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                      tempScope = scope;
                    }
                  });
                  w.bind('click', function(event){
                    var currentEle = $(event.target);
                    //$rootScope.$broadcast('dropdown:close');
                    if(tempScope.menu && !(currentEle.hasClass('main-menu'))) {
                      console.log(tempScope);
                      tempScope.menu.showSubMenu=false;
                      tempScope.$apply();
                    }
                  });
                }
            };
    }];
});
}());
```